# getJSON requests looping through an array of parameters with delay between each call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, loops

Can anyone help me understand why the following jQuery/Javascript code, rather than running at a rhythmic 1-per-second-ish beat rate, instead has this cascading avalanche of ajax calls (slow to many-per-second)?

```
var i = 0, l = data.length;

function geocode() {

$.getJSON(
    'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
    {
        key: "xxxxx",
        sensor: false,
        address: data[i][3],
        region: 'gb'
    },
    function(d, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if(d["status"] == "OK") {
            console.log(data[i][3]);
            console.log(d["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]);
            i++;
            if(i < l) { window.setInterval(geocode, 1000); }
        }
    }
);

}

geocode();
```

In my head this flows thus:

1. Call geocode the first time
2. Ajax request is made
3. On success (which is an arbitrary amount of time later) I read the results
4. Increment the index
5. If we've not yet expended the array, set up another call to geocode to start in 1 second

For reference: "data" is a nested array of UK postcodes which I'm trying to retrieve coordinates for using Google's geocoding API.

Comment: how does it even get into the if statement?  `1 isn't < 1`

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ What you read as a "1" is actually an "l" (for lima).

Comment: How's that? `var i = 0,` then `i++;
            if(i < l)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You keep setting a new interval and never cancel the previous one. You should either cancel the interval using `clearInterval()` or use a one off `setTimeout`.

If you use an interval then when you set the interval save the value:

```
var intervalId;
....
intervalId = setInterval(...);
```

then

```
clearInterval(intervalId);
```

when you need a new interval. 
OR use `setTimeout()` and reissue as required.

Comment: As soon as you said it I spotted it. I'm using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`. My fault. Thanks

Comment: @chrsmrrtt. Glad you got it.